# How can i merge two object both Class and Generic List<T> use LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

How can i merge two object both Class and Generic List according to followed example?

```
public class BookShop
{
    public Author Author { get; set; }
    public List<Book> Book { get; set; }
}

public class Author
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class BookDetail
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public int BookID { get; set; }
}

List<BookShop> shop = db.GetBook();
List<BookDetail> bookDetail = db.GetBookDetail();

var merge = shop.Select(m => m.Book.Join(bookDetail, ok => ok.ID, ik => ik.BookID, (b, d) => new
{
    b.ID,
    b.Name,
    d.Comment
}));
```

So far so everything is okay, but i need to Author detail (Author.Name)

Comment: Why isn't `Author` a property of `Book`?

Comment: I'd suggest re-organising the class structure

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, i want to declare Author entity as apart. Is wrong way according to you?

Comment: @GoranZooferic When I think of a book entity, the author of the book should definitely be a part of it. You also see that now you actually *need* it as a part of your result object.

Comment: Where do you need it?

Comment: I think you need a many-to-many table to organize it. Remember that a book can be writed by many authors, also a author can write a lot of books.

Comment: See Join examples on following webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're using entity framework. Your structure should look more like this:

```
public class Author
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Book> Books { get; set; } 
}

public class Book
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int AuthorID { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<BookDetail> Details { get; set; }
}

public class BookDetail
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public int BookID { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

This lets you have a direct connection between books, authors, and book details. Then in Linq you can just do something like this to get details on a book

```
Books.Select(x => new 
{
    ID = x.ID,
    Name = x.Name,
    Comments = x.Details.Select(d => d.Comment)
    Author = x.Author
})
```